# Undefined index: password

Tags: php

After successfully registration the following error appears:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: password
>
> Filename: models/user_model.php
>
> Line Number: 32

Code:

```
 function insert_data($data)
   { 

    $data_user=array(
      'email'=> $data['email'],
      'password'=> md5($data['password']),
      'status'=>'0'
      );   
     return $this->db->insert('users', $data_user); 

   }
```

Comment: while calling `insert_data($data);` make sure that `$data` has a key with name `password`. here `$data['password']` is not available that is the error.

Comment: Solved. Thnx @Tintu C Raju

Comment: Note that storing passwords as md5 hash is considered insecure nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the array of $data has 'password' data. You can check it by debuging with this script `die($data['password']);` so like this.

```
function insert_data($data)
   { 
die($data['password']);
    $data_user=array(
      'email'=> $data['email'],
      'password'=> md5($data['password']),
      'status'=>'0'
      );   
     return $this->db->insert('users', $data_user); 

   }
```

hopefully this can help you ;)